# SQL Server Compact Toolbox with disabled add connections options

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-ce-4

The original problem is that I'm trying to use SQL CE 4.0 with Entity Framework 5. I have applied the service pack 1, applied different hot fix (as suggested in different forums and blogs).

Now, I've read that SQL Server Compact Toolbox can manage these connections, but when I follow the steps, I get this menu :

[image]

Where the two first items should be enabled. My project is a C# WPF project. I've also read (from some post over a year ago) that only Asp.Net projects are supported with this feature (Why??), is this why I get the disabled menu items?

Comment: SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 must be properly installed and registered in machine.config for the Toolbox to Work (I am the developer of the Toolbox)

Comment: That's what I figured :) (I recognized your avatar from various forums where I saw your posts.) Thanks for specifying!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of anyone stumbling across this very same issue, I had uninstalled SQL CE 3.5 trying for "force" VisualStudio into *not* showing it. It seems to be hard-coded or something because it did not work.

I re-installed it (SQL CE 3.5) and the options are no longer disabled.